# How to display values from Firebase one by one, each time a button is clicked?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying out a news gallery,where each image has a description. Using Firebase and Glide, I was able to get the image to load up and change on the press of a button. I need the right description of the photo stored in my database to change every time I press the button.

```
textref =new Firebase("https://skcet1-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/galdesc");

        textref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Map<String,String> map=dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String desc=map.get("1");
                //String desc1=map.get()
                Galdesc.setText(desc);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to include your code? Otherwise it's impossible to understand where the problem originates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a section in your Firebase database named `photo_description`. In this section add the description for each image like this:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
yourRef.child("photo_description").child(photoId).setValue("Photo Description");
```

In which `photoId` is actually the exact id of your image that you are using and the argument of the `setValue()` method is the `description` of the image, which is a String.

To get a `description` out, please put a `listener` on the node `photo_description` and extract the description as desired.

Hope it helps.